# How to capture an image from webcam in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, webcam

See I have a hp laptop and I am trying to capture images through its webcam for my login system. I am a beginner in vb.net and I do not know how to connect my webcam unto the picturebox I  have in the form and capture the image and save it to the database which is sql server 2005 I am using visual studio 2008 by the way.. please help and provide answers that would be understood by beginners like me  Thank you